# Importing from oracle database validation check

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, oracle

I am trying to check if I have already imported data inside my database but I am finding difficulties to do this. Below is my code which I am using in backend, middle layer and front end. Can anyone please check to see what I am doing wrong. Thanks alot for your help.

Mike

**This is the backend code**

```
public static Boolean isImported(string date)
    {
        DatabaseAdapter dba = DatabaseAdapter.GetInstance();
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM FCR.LOAD_CONTROL " +
                          "WHERE LOAD_DATE = to_date('" + date + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy') ";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dba.QueryDatabase(sqlQuery));

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)

        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**This is the business logic code**

```
public static Boolean isImported(string date)

    {
        return DatabaseHandler.isImported(date);
    }
```

**This is the front end code**

```
if(BusinessLayerHandler.isImported(dateField.Text) == false)

            {
                try

                {
                    BusinessLayerHandler.ImportFromOrion(dateField.Text);
                    Alert("Imported");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Alert("Not Imported");
                }
            }
```

Comment: What problem are you having with this code?

Comment: i was able to import before adding the code: if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) to check if data is already imported.

Comment: I guess you have checked the date is indeed dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your load date contain time ?....if it does you need to truncate your load date to remove it: `TRUNC(LOAD_DATE)`